# Palindrome class help in C++

Tags: c++

Hi i am trying to write a palindrome class but am getting the wrong results.

[image]

I need to create a Palindrome class and return whether the phrase is a Palindrome.
Here is my code. 
Palindrome.h:

```
#ifndef PALINDROME_H
#define PALINDROME_H
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class Palindrome{
private:
   char str[1024];
   char s1[1024];
   char s2[1024];
   int a;
   int b;

public:
   Palindrome(char s2[1024], int a, int b)
   {
    s2[1024] = { 0 };
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
   }
   void removeNonLetters(char str[]);
   void lowerCase(char s1[]);
   bool isPalindrome(char s2[], int a, int b);
   }; // End of class definition


#endif
```

Palindrome.cpp:

```
#include "Palindrome.h"
void Palindrome::removeNonLetters(char str[])
{
    char s1[1024] = { 0 };

    int j = 0;
    int l1 = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] <= '9' && str[i] >= '0')
       {
            s1[j++] = str[i];
       }
       else if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
        || (str[i]) >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
       {
            s1[j++] = str[i];
       }
     }
    cout << s1 << endl;
}
  void Palindrome::lowerCase(char s1[])
 {
       char s2[1024] = { 0 };
       int l2 = strlen(s1);
       int g = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < l2; i++)
      {
          if (s1[i] >= 'a' && s1[i] <= 'z')
          {
             s2[g++] = s1[i];
          }
         else if (s1[i] >= 'A' && s1[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            s2[g++] = s1[i] + 32;
        }
    }
cout << s2 << endl;
}
bool Palindrome::isPalindrome(char s2[], int a, int b)
{
if (a >= b)
    return true;
    cout << "Yes" << endl;
if (s2[a] != s2[b])
   return false;
else
    return isPalindrome(s2, a + 1, b - 1); 
    cout << "No" << endl;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Palindrome.h"
int main()
{
    char str[1024] = { 0 };
    char s1[1024] = { 0 };
    char s2[1024] = { 0 };
    cout << "input a string:" << endl;

    cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));

    Palindrome removeNonLetters(char str[]);

    Palindrome lowerCase(char s1[]);

    int length = strlen(s2);

    Palindrome isPalindrome(s2, 0, length - 1); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use a `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: what is "wrong results" ? please provide your sample input and the output you get. Actually from the attached image it looks like you dont get any result but there is a runtime error, right?

Comment: Both `removeNonLetters` and `lowerCase` are functions, not objects. (They're declared but never defined.) There is no point in making a class out of this. You should probably review the earlier chapters of your book.

Comment: The immediate cause for the crash is that an array with 1024 elements is indexed from 0 to 1023, and `s2[1024] = { 0 };` writes outside of it. (That's not an assignment to an array of `char` but to a `char`.)

Answer (score 2):

You teacher may not like this, but this is how we do it in the real world.

First things first, reach for the standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
```

A function to strip non-alpha characters from a string:

```
std::string strip(std::string s)
{
    s.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(s),
                           std::end(s),
                           [](auto c) { return !std::isalpha(c); }),
            std::end(s));
    return s;
}
```

A function to transform a string to lower case:

```
std::string to_lower(std::string s)
{
    std::transform(std::begin(s),
                   std::end(s),
                   std::begin(s),
                   [](auto c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    return s;
}
```

A function to check that a string is the same in reverse as it is forwards:

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::equal(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
                      std::rbegin(s), std::rend(s));
}
```

Putting it all together in a test:

```
int main()
{
    auto word = std::string("a!b B <>A");
    if (is_palindrome(to_lower(strip(word)))) {
        std::cout << "palindrome" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "not palindrome" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Complete listing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

std::string strip(std::string s)
{
    s.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(s),
                           std::end(s),
                           [](auto c) { return !std::isalpha(c); }),
            std::end(s));
    return s;
}

std::string to_lower(std::string s)
{
    std::transform(std::begin(s),
                   std::end(s),
                   std::begin(s),
                   [](auto c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    return s;
}

bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::equal(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
                      std::rbegin(s), std::rend(s));
}

int main()
{
    auto word = std::string("a!b B <>A");
    if (is_palindrome(to_lower(strip(word)))) {
        std::cout << "palindrome" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "not palindrome" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code.  I hope these pointers help:

- You should be using std library.
- Why does the constructor for the class take any parameters? Nothign uses them
- Why are there any member variables? Nothing uses them.
- Why are the functions in a class at all?  They're just functions - they should be in a functions library or similar.
- The functions just write to cout so are useless.
- Your main function doesn't even seem to call the functions correctly.

I tried this:

```
char str[1024] = { 0 };
cout << "input a string:" << endl;

cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));

int length = strlen(str);
Palindrome a(str,0, length);
a.removeNonLetters(str);
a.lowerCase(str);
a.isPalindrome(str, 0, length - 1);

cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
return 0;
```

I don't get the exception but get the following output:

```
input a string:
EVIL rats on no star **** live
EVILratsonnostarlive
evilratsonnostarlive
Yes
```

However this works too:

```
input a string
hello
hello
hello
Yes
```

So the first two functions seem to work (if removing spaces was also intentional) but the third does not.